# Blank page on successful MySQL update

Tags: php

The updatesuccess.php script in the following PHP statement, is not executed;

```
Header("Location: updatesuccess.php");
```

The main update script successfully executes the record update on the MySQL DB, but the updatesuccess.php in the above statement is not executed, instead, a blank page is displayed. The updatesuccess.php only displays a message of a successful update.

Please, where is `Location` in the statement `Header("Location: updatesuccess.php")` referring to ?

Comment: A blank screen usually indicates a server problem. What does your server error log say?

Comment: no idea, but the proper case for `Header(...)` is `header(...)`. You're going to have to at the very least tell us what you're actually using (e.g. framework, cms, self-written code, etc) and probably show some actual code with indications on where in that code it goes wrong (and not 1000s of lines of code, but reduced to a minimal example)

Comment: Do read this > http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting a question, and with no additional code provided to *possibly* help find a solution. Not doing so, your question may get closed for a number of reasons.

Comment: Are you outputting anything before the header call?  You cannot use `header()` after something is output.

Comment: OK. I'd wanted to post the whole script as an image, but I don't have 10 reputations because I'm new to the forum. In any case it is a self-written code. Here is the portion of the code where the Blank page issue arises:

**$query = "UPDATE lifeindiv SET cedant_code='$cedant_code', ... WHERE lifeid='$lifeid'";** (Please note that I've deliberately TRUNCATED this statement because of its long length)  

**$result = mysql_query($query,$con);

 if (!$result)
 { 
 echo mysql_error();
 } 
 else 
 { 
 Header("Location: updatesuccess.php");
 }

 mysql_close($con); 

}**